# Sortable divs being pushed down in swim lanes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a board with sortable swim lanes that contain multiple div items (think of a horizontal kanban board).  When I grab an item to move it though all of the items in the swim lane are pushed down.  I've been banging my head on this so I'm hoping you guys can help me.

Here's a link to my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pheeper/cy6mqs7n/2/)

```js
   $(function() {
      $(".swim-lane-wrapper")
        .sortable({
        axis: "Y",
        handle: ".category-box",
        connectWith: ".swim-lane-wrapper",
      })
        .disableSelection();
    });
    
    $(function() {
      $(".sortable")
        .sortable({
        connectWith: ".sortable",
      })
        .disableSelection();
    });
```

```css
   .swim-lane {
      display: inline-block;
      white-space: nowrap;
      float: left;
      width: 90%;
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    .category-box {
      display: inline-block;
      white-space: nowrap;
      float: left;
      background-color: #FFF3CC;
      border: #DFBC6A 1px solid;
      width: 75px;
      height: 50px;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 12px;
      white-space: normal;
      text-align: center;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
      cursor: move;
    }
    
    .item-box {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #edf3ff;
      border: #6d71db 1px solid;
      width: 75px;
      height: 50px;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 12px;
      white-space: normal;
      text-align: center;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
      cursor: move;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylsheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
    
    
    <div class="swim-lane-wrapper">
    
      <!-- Row One -->
      <div class="swim-lane">  
        <div class="category-box">"Category 1"</div>
        <div class="sortable">
          <div class="item-box">"Wrap this long string of text please!"</div>
          <div class="item-box">"Wrap this long string of text please!"</div>
          <div class="item-box">"Wrap this long string of text please!"</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <!-- Row Two -->
      <div class="swim-lane">
        <div class="category-box">"Category 2"</div>
        <div class="sortable">
          <div class="item-box">"Wrap this long string of text please!"</div>
          <div class="item-box">"Wrap this long string of text please!"</div>
          <div class="item-box">"Wrap this long string of text please!"</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to `.item-box`

```js
$(function() {
      $(".swim-lane-wrapper")
        .sortable({
        axis: "Y",
        handle: ".category-box",
        connectWith: ".swim-lane-wrapper",
      })
        .disableSelection();
    });
    
    $(function() {
      $(".sortable")
        .sortable({
        connectWith: ".sortable",
      })
        .disableSelection();
    });
```

```css
.swim-lane {
      display: inline-block;
      white-space: nowrap;
      float: left;
      width: 90%;
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    .category-box {
      display: inline-block;
      white-space: nowrap;
      float: left;
      background-color: #FFF3CC;
      border: #DFBC6A 1px solid;
      width: 75px;
      height: 50px;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 12px;
      white-space: normal;
      text-align: center;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
      cursor: move;
    }
    
    .item-box {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      background-color: #edf3ff;
      border: #6d71db 1px solid;
      width: 75px;
      height: 50px;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 12px;
      white-space: normal;
      text-align: center;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
      cursor: move;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylsheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
    
    
    <div class="swim-lane-wrapper">
    
      <!-- Row One -->
      <div class="swim-lane">  
        <div class="category-box">"Category 1"</div>
        <div class="sortable">
          <div class="item-box">"Wrap this long string of text please!"</div>
          <div class="item-box">"Wrap this long string of text please!"</div>
          <div class="item-box">"Wrap this long string of text please!"</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <!-- Row Two -->
      <div class="swim-lane">
        <div class="category-box">"Category 2"</div>
        <div class="sortable">
          <div class="item-box">"Wrap this long string of text please!"</div>
          <div class="item-box">"Wrap this long string of text please!"</div>
          <div class="item-box">"Wrap this long string of text please!"</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer of @manuel but I wrtie this solution for who looks for the reason behind this problem. The UI sortable uses a temporary placeholder with the class name of `.ui-sortable-placeholder`  in the place of the hanged element. This is a hidden element with the same width and height of main element. It has no extra styles and is not defined in the UI CSS file.

You can specify the height of this hidden element by this hacky style and prevent neighbor elements to loose their position:

```
 .ui-sortable-placeholder {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 1px;
   }
```